# Is there a way to mark a NSManagedObject as dirty?

Tags: ios, core-data

In my NSManagedObject subclass I have an NSString ivar that splits up into an NSSet of entities.  I'd like to be able to set the string and during a call to save, do the split, however, only setting the string will not trigger a dirty flag or a need to save.

Comment: Did you come up with an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `+ (BOOL)contextShouldIgnoreUnmodeledPropertyChanges` on you `NSManagedObject` subclass and return `NO` rather than the default (`YES`).

This should then cause the `NSManagedObjectContext` to be notified of changes properties even if they aren't represented by actual columns in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "attribute" instead of "ivar". Your scheme of having a string being split into a set and then saving the set is perhaps debatable, but I guess that is not the issue here.

Why do you need to have the Managed Object marked as "dirty"? This is really not necessary. Just save it, dirty or not!

I do not know how you check the "dirtiness" of your managed object, but I assume you want this to trigger a save at a certain point. At that point you might just as well as check your own `BOOL` "dirtyFlag" which you can set as appropriate and keep available for checking.

It is always better to make these kinds of things explicit. Your code will become more readable and transparent.

Comment: No, it is an ivar in my subclass, not in the MOC file.  It doesn't touch the database at all.  I want to split the string in -willSave.

Comment: Do you save the parts that you will split out of the string?

Comment: Here's a case where you'd want to mark an object dirty: so that it shows up in the subsequent NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification as an updated object. Then any NSFetchedResultsControllers for which it is a candidate will notice and reevaluate it.