# Propagate CoreData changes to related objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Is there a way to have changes to an object's attribute also "alert" related objects?

The structure we have is as follows:

- `Image` has an attribute called `content`
- `Category` has a one-to-one relationship to `Image`

It would be ideal if changes to attributes within the `Image` object could be detected by the related `Category`, in a way that the `Category` would be included in the `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` of `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`. I've seen some suggestions indicating that adding a sentinel attribute such as `needsUpdate` to `Category` would be a good way to do this, but that seems like a cumbersome way of handling this.

My reasoning for doing this is that I need to reload a tableview whenever a `Category` changes, or whenever it's associated `Image` changes, at the moment in my observation method for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` I check updated/deleted/inserted objects for `Image` instances or `Category` instances, however `Image` instances are used elsewhere in the app and may have no relationship to a `Category` instance, in which case it would be a waste to reload the tableview. I could manually loop through the updated/deleted/inserted objects to see if they are `Image` instances associated with a `Category`, but that doesn't seem like the best place to do it.

I found that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423059/is-there-a-way-to-mark-a-nsmanagedobject-as-dirty) is similar to what I am attempting, however it has no answer.

Please let me know if additional information is needed, or if my question is too convoluted.

Edit: Modified to hopefully make it more apparent that I'm interested in `Category` being aware of changes within the `Image` object's attributes, rather than a change in the relationship itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest learning about KVO (Key Value Observing) as that framework is designed specifically for this purpose.  With KVO you can listen to a specific object for changes on its attributes and then react to them.

However, I question why you are not using a `NSFetchedResultsController` for this.  That is what the `NSFetchedResultsController` is designed for.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it is about tracking changes to related objects. NSFetchedResultsController does not do that on its own, as some master of Core Data told us: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7534013/1187415.

Comment: Watching Category and if the Image relationship changes then it would fire.  From my read of the OP, the relationship would change, not the data inside of the image object.

Comment: I agree that using an `NSFetchedResultsController` likely would have been useful, however as mentioned by @MartinR I don't think it would adequately solve the issue at hand (at least by itself). I don't have a good reason as to why I didn't use `NSFetchedResultsController`, I was likely unfamiliar with CoreData when I originally implemented the tableview (thus did things the hard way) and never found enough reason to refactor it to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` afterwards.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra sorry for the ambiguity, but I am interested in detecting a change when the data inside the `Image` object is modified, as opposed to the relationship being changed. I'll update the question to make this more apparent.

Comment: Then in that case my original suggestion stands.  You can use KVO to add your view controller as a watcher for that data or you can continue to filter through the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notifications.  Personally, based on my experience, filtering through the notifications is cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Ok, so I take it that CoreData isn't able to support this functionality (at least at the moment). Like you suggested, filtering is a good alternative. It might help others if you include that in your original answer, so they don't have to dig through the comments.

Comment: @Arkcann, Core Data is not a single framework/utility.  Most of what people consider "Core Data" is in fact the core of Objective-C.  Does Core Data support what you want?  Yes, through KVO which is part of how Core Data works.  To make a statement that it doesn't support the functionality is incorrect because it implies that Core Data is a stand alone framework.